# Disable Port from command line (CMD) (Devcon it can not disable a port when there is nothing plug in; I need to do this 100+ PC)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

How do I disable this port from command line?
Is it possible to disable Port#0005 and only Port#0005?

[image: Port005]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267236/how-disable-and-enable-usb-port-via-command-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable and enable a USB port via command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/502046/how-to-disable-and-enable-a-usb-port-via-command-prompt)

Comment: The problem with this it disable all ports. I just need to disable one.

Comment: While the marked answer in the possible duplicate (which you cannot see) disabled all ports, the most-upvoted answer appears to show how to disable a specific port. Have you tried this?

Comment: I am testing "Possible duplicate of How to disable and enable a USB port via command prompt?" . I was reply to stackoverflow.com/questions/13267236/

Comment: The main problem with  "How to disable and enable a USB port via command prompt?" is it can not disable a port when there is nothing plug in.

Comment: I need to do this 100+ PC

Comment: If you're dealing with Dell devices you can pre-configure BIOS settings (which include USB port deactivation) and push those BIOS images to computers using Dell Command Configure.

Comment: Nope, not Dell.