# How to enable and disable power to a USB port on command

Tags: usb

I want to be able to enable and disable the power to a specific USB port. Without restarting my PC, and simply turn it on and off with a key bind. I'm okay with getting hardware to do so, (Raspberry Pi, USB Hub, Etc.) however I'm unsure what to do with it once I have it.
Edit: OS Windows 11. I do not want to use Devcon as stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/502046/how-to-disable-and-enable-a-usb-port-via-command-prompt), because all it did was disable the driver itself, not the power outputted. It's just a simple device (USB Desk Lamp, Fan, Etc.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable and enable a USB port via command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/502046/how-to-disable-and-enable-a-usb-port-via-command-prompt)

Comment: I was able to Disable the driver, but not the device itself. I want to be able to control the power via my pc, rather than unplugging and plugging in the device. As I stated before, I'm okay with getting external hardware such as a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What OS? What hardware? You've presented a very broad query without giving much detail. You've been given a viable solution but have not given a reason other than preference for not wanting it. Please use the EDIT button to make your requirements, specifications, and problem more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here and didn't know how detailed it needed to be. I didn't want to go too much into detail to begin with as I felt like that was overwhelming. If there is anything I have missed or more detail I need to provide, please let me know and I'll be happy to contribute.